# Which technique should I use to consume a .NET Web Service from the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, web-services, protocols

The description page for my .NET web Service includes 4 different protocols to use to consume it.

- SOAP 1.1
- SOAP 1.2
- HTTP GET
- HTTP POST

In my work-in-progress iPhone application I have used both SOAP 1.1 and HTTP GET to access the XML data and am then parsing to get the information I want.

I'm now refactoring the application and am creating a Data Library class that will use code-reuse to make my current data operations easier to maintain.

SOAP 1.1 seems straight forward enough, if a little unwieldy, are there any benefits for me  to use SOAP 1.2 on the iPhone. I'm presuming the differences will have little consequence when all I'm doing is basic XML parsing for strings.

Also HTTP Get seems the easiest of the lot! A simple **dataWithContentsOfURL** appears sufficient to get what I need, I don't even need to do a post.

Are there any idiosyncrasies on the iPhone that make any of these techniques better than others?

I'm going to research a REST services now. I think I understand the concept of stateless but not sure how it applies to the 4 options above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataWithContentsOfURL
```

Has always worked for me with no problems.